# How to create/write a text file instead of uploading to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

Is there a method to write/create a text file to S3 bucket in AWS SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may helpful. I use ZenS3 (https://github.com/cyberbuff/ZenS3). It has a method putObjectString(). Just pass string to putObjectString method. It will create a file in S3 Bucket. Make sure your bucket should be in US region.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 works via HTTP REST API.

There are methods in the SDK's to write a string to a file in S3: for example the [set_contents_from_string](https://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html) method.

There are different S3 clients that provide an ease of use to S3 like [CloudBerry](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/free-amazon-s3-explorer-cloudfront-IAM.aspx) and [DragonDisk](http://www.dragondisk.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Can use this overload of [AmazonS3.putObject()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#putObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-). REST API described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/goto/WebAPI/s3-2006-03-01/PutObject).

"*content: The String to encode*" will be written to the file as content as it is. Word ***encode*** might be a bit confusing.

```
/**
 * <p>
 * Encodes a String into the contents of an S3 object.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * String will be encoded to bytes with UTF-8 encoding.
 * </p>
 *
 * @param bucketName
 *            The name of the bucket to place the new object in.
 * @param key
 *            The key of the object to create.
 * @param content
 *            The String to encode
 * @see <a href="http://docs.aws.amazon.com/goto/WebAPI/s3-2006-03-01/PutObject">AWS API Documentation</a>
 */
public PutObjectResult putObject(String bucketName, String key, String content)
        throws AmazonServiceException, SdkClientException;
```